How can I make a search bar in django?
I'm learning django and I'm trying to make a online shop for learning. Currently I have a problem in how to make a search bar in django.
I have model called "Car" in my models.py and it contains fields like name, price of the car and also it has a field called "tag" and I want to make a search bar using this field. I want that when user types a tag in the webpage of site, django searches and shows the items that have the same tag.
I tried to solve my problem by reading the documents but it didn't help.

Does this answer your question? Search Bar in Django

Solution
Here is an example of a view and some template code that would handle the search you want to execute (adapted from Bidhan Majhi's answer to this StackOverflow question):
views.py
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
       result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
       query = self.request.GET.get('search')
       if query:
          postresult = Car.objects.filter(tag__contains=query)
          result = postresult
       else:
           result = None
       return result

template
<form method="GET" action="" >
    <input type="search" name="search"> 
    <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>

{% for car in all_search_results %}
   <h2>{{ car.year }}&nbsp;{{ car.make }}&nbsp;{{ car.model }}</h2>
   {% comment %} Add whatever else for each Car model returned{% endcomment %}
{% empty %}
   <h2>add something to show no results</h2>
{% endfor %}

Caveat (if your tags field is a ManyToManyField)
The above view would work as long as your tag is just a CharField, but if your tags field is a ManyToManyField, you would have to modify the postresult = Car.objects.filter(tag__contains=query) line so that it would work through a related Tag model (postresult = Car.objects.filter(tags__text__contains=query)).
This is how that would look:
app named "tag": models.py
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

app named "car": models.py
from django.db import models
from tag.models import Tag

import datetime

def year_range():
    this_year = datetime.date.today().year
    return [(r, r) for r in range(
            1860, this_year+2
        )
    ]

class Car(models.Model):
    """model for thoughts that come into my mind"""
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=year_range
    )
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag, related_name="cars"
    )

views.py
from django.views import generic

from .models import Car


# Create your views here.
class SearchView(generic.ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            postresult = Car.objects.filter(tags__text__contains=query)
            result = postresult
        else:
            result = None
        return result

The template would be the same as above. I just tried it in a django sandbox project I have, and it worked great :)
